# Owner entity type person is not supported Linkedin

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

When I try to share in linkedin using https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares
I am getting error.

```
{
  "message": "Owner entity type person is not supported",
  "status": 400
}
```

Data I send in body is

```
{
 "content": {
    "title": "Test Share with Content"
 },
 "owner": "urn:li:person:anuroop-francis-29278068",
 "subject": "Test Share Subject",
 "text": {
    "text": "Test Share!"
 }
}
```

Comment: Which OAuth permission scopes have you requested? You need to request the `w_member_social` permission in order to submit a POST request to /v2/shares API if you are using a Person URN.

Comment: Hey @anuroop-francis, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the `owner` field.
This particular error is caused by the wrong profile id `anuroop-francis-29278068` that you use in value `urn:li:person:anuroop-francis-29278068`.
It looks like you take id from the profile link `https://www.linkedin.com/in/anuroop-francis-29278068/`.

All you need to do is put the right profile id inside the `owner` field value.
One of the easiest ways to get the right profile id is to hit the `GET` `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` endpoint from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/marketing/context#request). In the response you can find a field with the profile id you need:

```
{
  ...
  "id":"yrZCpj2Z12",
  ...
}
```

Then just put this value in your `owner` field:

```
{
  ...
  "owner": "urn:li:person:yrZCpj2Z12",
  ...
}
```

And now when you hit the `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares` endpoint you are going to have a shared post on the given user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are sending distribution object something like below

```
"distribution": {
    "linkedInDistributionTarget": []
}
```

Notice linkedInDistributionTarget is array but it should be object according to doc.

[Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWqnX.png)